# MassTransit and RabbitMQ are working locally, but messages are skipped in production

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have an email service, `EnduroMailer`, installed as a Windows service on our production machine. EnduroMailer communicates with RabbitMQ over MassTransit to pick up any emails waiting in the queue, and it sends them.

My code to send a request to RabbitMQ looks like the following:

```cs
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly ISendEndpointProvider _endpointProvider;

    public EmailService(ISendEndpointProvider endpointProvider)
    {
        _endpointProvider = endpointProvider;
    }

    public async Task SendEmail(string recipient, string from, string subject, string body,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var endpoint = await _endpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:send-email"));
        var request = new
        {
            From = from,
            Recipient = recipient,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        };
        
        await endpoint.Send<ISendEmail>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And the consumer in EnduroMailer looks like so:

```cs
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISendEmail> context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Request received.");
    
    using var message = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(context.Message.From),
        Body = context.Message.Body,
        Subject = context.Message.Subject,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };
    message.To.Add(context.Message.Recipient);
    
    await _client.SendMailAsync(message);
    await context.RespondAsync<IEmailSent>(new {context.Message.Recipient});
}
```

When I run the standalone email service on my local machine, it picks up all the pending emails from the queue and begins sending them. However, when I have it hosted as a windows service, the messages get placed into the `send-email_skipped` queue. One of those messages looks like:

```
message_id: 1d010000-5d03-0015-e776-08d82827f7d4
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
Content-Type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
MT-Activity-Id: |4988b6ad-4641fe692ecfa3d7.1.
MT-Host-Assembly:   EnduroMail
MT-Host-AssemblyVersion:    1.0.0.0
MT-Host-FrameworkVersion:   3.1.1
MT-Host-MachineName:    HERMES
MT-Host-MassTransitVersion: 6.3.2.0
MT-Host-OperatingSystemVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
MT-Host-ProcessId:  4576
MT-Host-ProcessName:    EnduroMail
MT-Reason:  dead-letter
publishId:  2
content_type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json

{
  "messageId": "1d010000-5d03-0015-e776-08d82827f7d4",
  "conversationId": "1d010000-5d03-0015-7c48-08d82827f7da",
  "sourceAddress": "rabbitmq://192.168.250.194/HERMES_w3wp_bus_dwyoyyn7ycybkscrbdcnojqq8p?temporary=true",
  "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://192.168.250.194/send-email?bind=true",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:Enduro.Common.Messages.Requests:ISendEmail"
  ],
  "message": {
    "from": "REDACTED",
    "recipient": "REDACTED",
    "subject": "REDACTED",
    "body": "REDACTED"
  },
  "sentTime": "2020-07-14T18:58:59.9686006Z",
  "headers": {
    "MT-Activity-Id": "|4988b6ad-4641fe692ecfa3d7.1."
  },
  "host": {
    "machineName": "HERMES",
    "processName": "w3wp",
    "processId": 1636,
    "assembly": "PigTrack.Presentation",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "3.1.1",
    "massTransitVersion": "6.3.2.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0"
  }
}
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Is the `ISendEmail` consumer the only consumer receiving on the `send-email` queue? You can look at the RabbitMQ management console, find the queue, and expand the Consumers section to see the connections and show the process info on the connection client properties.

Comment: Check the docs also https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#skipped-messages. There's some zombie binding, like Chris said.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson yes, the consumer listed above is the only consumer listed inside of the `send-email` queue.

Comment: Message type, including namespace, matches what the consumer expects? Receive endpoint configured correctly with the consumer?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I'm assuming as much, especially considering the fact that it works when ran locally through the IDE, but it fails when it's being ran as a `WorkerService` under Windows Services.